# Flutter - launch email clients WITHOUT sending an email and knowing which client(s) a user might use

Tags: flutter

Need to offer a user a button to open their email client if they are using password-less authentication.

Have looked at url_launcher, but it's wants to create an email, the app_availability wants specific package names or just default email for ios...

Has anyone come across a way to just show a user a snackbar with whatever email clients they might have on their device?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender

u can use this code

```
FlutterEmailSender.send(Email(recipients: ['emailid@email.com'],subject: 'any subject you want'));
```

user will be shown all the available email clients, he can choose any of the clients

Comment: thanks, but happens once a user chooses a client - does it create an email within that client as the params suggest? That'd be incorrect for this use case as the task is to check for incoming emails, not write outgoing ones.